# js:Getting wrong answer when given integer is bigger in Fibonacci number algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sum, fibonacci

I am working on a Fibonacci numbers question below:

> Given a positive integer num, return the sum of all odd Fibonacci
>   numbers that are less than or equal to num. For example, sumFibs(10)
>   should return 10 because all odd Fibonacci numbers less than or equal
>   to 10 are 1, 1, 3, and 5.

```
sumFibs(1) should return a number.
sumFibs(1000) should return 1785.
sumFibs(4000000) should return 4613732.
sumFibs(4) should return 5.
sumFibs(75024) should return 60696.
sumFibs(75025) should return 135721.
```

Below is my solution. I confused why I get wrong sum of total when the given integer num equal to 4000000, but other output are fine.Thanks.

```
function FindFib(num){   
    if(num === 0)
       return 0;    
    else if(num === 1)
       return 1;    
    else
       return FindFib(num-2) + FindFib(num-1); 
}

function sumFibs(num) {    
  var total=0;   
  var fib=0;

  for(var i =0;i<=num;i++){

    fib = FindFib(i);

    if(fib%2 === 1 && fib <= num)
      total=total+fib;         
   }
     return total;    
}

console.log(sumFibs(400000));
```

Comment: your solution works for sumFibs(399999)?

Comment: sumFibs(399999) is not work too i think. I cannot find where logic missing

Comment: The given 1,1000,4,75024,75025 is work.@Fallen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FindFib method will not work as fibonacci numbers get big very quickly.

Note that if the nth Fibonacci is greater than any number X, then n+1th fibonacci number is also larger than X. With that in mind, we can stop upon finding the first fibonacci number that exceeds N.

So we can rewrite the `sumFibs` method as,

```
function sumFibs(num) {    
  var total=0;   
  var fib=0;
  for(var i = 0;i <= num; i++){
    fib = FindFib(i);
    if(fib > num)break;
    if(fib%2 === 1)
      total=total+fib;         
   }
   return total;    
}
```

Also you can find the nth fibonacci number with an iterative approach which is as simple as,

```
function findFib(n) {
    let fib = [];
    fib[0] = 1
    fib[1] = 1
    for(int i = 2; i <= n; ++i) {
        fib[i] = fib[i-1]+fib[i-2];
    }
    return fib[n];
}
```

Also, you can store the already calculated Fibonacci number to avoid huge load of recalculation, and save memory and time.

Comment: One can improve even further by, instead of using an array, simply swapping the variables. This would use constant memory.

Comment: True but I wanted to give a hint about how to memoize it on the go ;)